# write operation partially completes

Tags: python, python-idle

I am a python newbie and here is my code to extract some numbers from lines of text in a file:

```
i = 0
path = '/home/vahid/git/simmobility/dev/Basic/pathset/'
output = open(path + 'noTTSectionResult.txt', 'w')
for row in open(path + 'heoutput.txt', 'r'):
    if row.find('error: getTravelTimeBySegId') == -1 :
        continue
    words = row.split(':')
    word = words[3]
    word = word[1:]
    word = word[:-3]
    output.write(str(i) + ':' +word + '\n')
    i = i+1
print i
output.close
```

the final output printed on console is 999 (I even printed the result in console to make sure)but the number of lines written into the output file is less-754 lines! even the last line is written partially!!!
Am I missing something?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

```
output.close
```

should be

```
output.close()
```

Otherwise it's a no-op and does not close the file. If the file is not closed, the write buffer is not flushed until later, or at all (depending on how your script terminates).

To avoid having to explicitly close the file, you could use the [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

```
with open(path + 'noTTSectionResult.txt', 'w') as output:
   for row in open(path + 'heoutput.txt', 'r'):
      ...
      output.write(...)
      ...
# no need to explicitly close `output'
```

This has the added advantage of closing the file even if the `for` loops raises an exception.

Comment: You just access to the `close` function but didn't call it. Try to write in a python console `>>> open`. The string representation of the `open` function is printed and correspond to the function not the call. It's like the difference between f and f(x) in math

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush your output's buffer with the `flush()` method on python file objects.

Also, if you want to de sure all the content of the buffer is really written on your hard drive (or something else), you have to use the system call `os.fsync()`

The `'close()` method on file object normally flush the buffer. But I think it's good o know how it's working.